# Intended use of appProject in vscode docker-build task

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, dockerfile, vscode-tasks

Some context: I'm learning to use docker. I have a manually written `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` file but when I stand up the container and the netcoreapp3.1 Kestrel web app contained therein, there's a problem loading the SSL certificate. The cert file isn't visible to Kestrel for reasons yet unknown to me.

In the process of fathoming this, I discovered VS Code has support for `docker-build` tasks. I've excerpted the interesting portion of [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/reference#_netcore-object-properties-dockerrun-task) below.

The part that confuses me is the mandatory `appProject` property. My `Dockerfile` pulls source from git; several related projects. Then it compiles it and does various other things. Why do I need to specify an app project in the task when that sort of thing is defined by the `Dockerfile`? I strongly suspect I have failed to understand how these tasks are intended to be used — something the docs don't really address.

Could someone please explain the intended mode of use and the relevance of these settings? Preferably with examples.

> #### Docker build task
>
> The `docker-build task` builds Docker images using the Docker command line (CLI). The task can be used by itself, or as part of a chain of tasks to run and/or debug an application within a Docker container.
>
> The most important configuration settings for the `docker-build` task are `dockerBuild` and `platform`:
>
> - The `dockerBuild` object specifies parameters for the Docker build command. Values specified by this object are applied directly to Docker build CLI invocation.
> - The `platform` property is a hint that changes how the `docker-build` task determines Docker build defaults.
>
> #### Platform support#
>
> While the `docker-build` task in `tasks.json` can be used to build any Docker image, the extension has explicit support (and simplified configuration) for Node.js, Python, and .NET Core
>
> #### .NET Core (docker-build)#
>
> ##### Minimal configuration using defaults
>
> When you build a .NET Core-based Docker image, you can omit the `platform` property and just set the `netCore` object (`platform` is implicitly set to `netcore` when `netCore` object is present). Note that `appProject` is a required property:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build Node Image",
      "type": "docker-build",
      "netCore": {
        "appProject": "${workspaceFolder}/project.csproj"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> ##### Platform defaults
>
> For .NET Core-based images, the `docker-build` task infers the following options:

| Property | Inferred Value |
| --- | --- |
| `dockerBuild.context` | The root workspace folder. |
| `dockerBuild.dockerfile` | The file `Dockerfile` in the root workspace folder. |
| `dockerBuild.tag` | The base name of the root workspace folder. |

Comment: The busted table at the end of the docs excerpt works fine as a child of a blockquote in the edit mode preview. If anyone knows how to fix it please do.